# After jumping to the xref operand of a function I found via string searching in IDA, I am brought to an rdata section?

Tags: ida

First post here, so sorry. I'll try to keep it short. Anyways, when trying to xref an operand (to find its offset), it brings me to an rdata function. It looks like this:

```
.rdata:00000001419318D8                 dq offset aFhealth      ; "fHealth"
```

Any idea how I can get the offset from this? It's the only thing that shows up when I search for fHealth in the strings view, and in this game the game itself is stored in the exe, not in another dll.

Comment: You can look at the base of the binary View > Open Subviews > Segments(Shift + F7) and find out the base address the binary has been loaded. Then you subtract base from 0x1419318D8 to get the offset.